# I am unable to extract the correct xpath , can help me

Tags: java, selenium, xpath-2.0

[image]

For xpath plaese help me for get xpath

Comment: i have tried to xpath but not correct this is xpath //*[@id="header_height"]/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]/span

Comment: does `//span[@class="reg_icon"]` give multiple matches?

Comment: please try `//*[@class='reg_icon']`

Comment: please edit your post to add xpath requests you have tried, also explain what you want to get with the xpath you are asking.
And if you could copy/paste html instead of an image, it would be great for us to help you

Comment: @Maelig hey all are paste on this post can you please view my pasted image

Comment: @Frian try //*[@class='reg_icon']  not working again error is appearing

Comment: add xpath requests by editing the main post, so people coming to help do not have to read all comments, just saying that so you have a good post, and good post got better/quicker help

Comment: @zafarahmad post the html code as text, not as a image, that's what Maelig was asking for.

Comment: @zafarahmad please post html code

Comment: Can you add your HTML output here please, with this i can make very fast your solution.

Comment: sure i am adding

Comment: <div class="fr mt-header">
                        <a id="checkPrice" class="fl check-price" onclick="checkPrice()"><span class="check-price-icon"></span></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="registrationBtn" title="Client-Patient Registration" onclick="javascript:return OpenKendoPopupWindow('Registration', '/Client/Create?source=Main', 620, 645, false,false);">
<span class="reg_icon"></span>

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="registrationBtn" title="Client-Patient Registration" onclick="javascript:return OpenKendoPopupWindow('Registration', '/Client/Create?source=Main', 620, 645, false,false);">
                            <span class="reg_icon"></span>
                        </a>

Comment: i need hit this Client-Patient Registration

Comment: @deoncagadoes pasted HTML

Comment: @zafarahmad Can you add full source, from <html> to </html> Add in your post, and messageme when you do.

Comment: @deoncagadoes             this is not possible for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try //a[@class='registrationBtn']/span[1]

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element induce [**WebDriverWait**](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and wait for the element `elementToBeClickable` and then click.

Try following code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='fr mt-header']/a[@class='registrationBtn' and @title='Client-Patient Registration']")));
element.click()
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='fr mt-header']/a[@class='registrationBtn' and @title='Client-Patient Registration']/span[@class='reg_icon']")));
element.click()
```